# hierarchy comparisons in python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I have to do hierarchy comparisons and observe changes then highlight with color codings with Python in Excel. For example as below are my datasets:

[image: data1,previous]

[image: data2,current]

I am looking for the output below:

[image: expected output in excel]

Below are my datasets and I am using pandas but data is not sorted order and few columns are missing in my output excel.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook,
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill packages 

current_data_str = """L1,L2,L3
manager1,e1,e5
manager1,e1,e5
manager2,e2,e6
manager2,e2,e7
manager3,e3,e8
manager3,e4,e9
manager3,e4,e10"""

previous_data_str = """L1,L2,L3
manager1,e1,e5
manager1,e1,e5
e6,e13,
e6,e14,
e8,e15,
e9,e16,
e17,,"""
```

Comment: You should include some actual code.

Answer (score 2):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), assuming both dfs have always the same shape, you can [`compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) them :

```
# to be replaced with any equivalent
curr = pd.read_csv(StringIO(current_data_str))
prev = pd.read_csv(StringIO(previous_data_str))

# compare between current and previous table
cmp = (curr.compare(prev, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True,
        result_names=("previous", "current"))
       .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map(
           lambda c: "{}_{}".format(*c)), axis=1)))

# highlight the differences
s = (cmp.style.apply(lambda s: np.where(
    ~cmp.notna().all(axis=1), "background-color: yellow", ""))
         .format(na_rep=""))

# s.to_excel("comparison.xlsx") # uncomment to make a new spreadsheet
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.compare` with a little reindexing and column naming:

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'L1':'m1 m1 m2 m2 m3 m3 m3'.split(),
                  'L2':'e1 e1 e2 e2 e3 e4 e4'.split(),
                  'L3':'e5 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 e10'.split(),
                  'L4':'e11 e12 e13 e14 e15 e16 e17'.split()})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'L1':'m1 m1 e6 e6 e8 e9 e17'.split(),
                    'L2':'e1 e1 e13 e14 e15 e16'.split()+[np.nan],
                    'L3':['e5']*2+[np.nan]*5,
                    'L4':['e11', 'e12']+[np.nan]*5})

dfc = df.compare(df2, result_names=('previous','current')).fillna('True').notna()
dfc.columns = dfc.columns.map('_'.join)

dfs = df.compare(df2, result_names=('previous','current'), keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
dfs.columns = dfs.columns.map('_'.join)

m = dfc.reindex_like(dfs).notna()

dfs.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(~m[x.name],'','background-color: yellow;'))#.to_excel('a2.xlsx')
```

Output:

[image]